# cannot read property 'params' of undefined react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm coding product detail but can't use the params property

Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
you can see my code here

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const ProductDetail = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const productID = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Product Detail</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

Product Item

```
const CardHeight = 220;
const ProductItem = ({list}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {list?.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: sizes.radius,
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('ProductDetails'), {productID: index};
                  }}>
                  .....
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

MainNavigator

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <Stack.Navigator>
        
        
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={TabDrawer}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            gestureEnabled: false,
          }}
        />
        
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ProductDetails"
          component={productDetailScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;
```

I tried to follow the Passing parameters to routes of react navigation without success
productDetail

I don't know where this error comes from can anyone explain to me specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this `navigation.navigate('ProductDetails'), {productID: index};` with below code:

```
navigation.navigate('ProductDetails',{productID: index})
```